# React-Native DateTimePicker in InputField

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, datetimepicker, exp

I have built DateTimePicker into an InputField for my Android app, but the DateTimePicker by default takes the width of its content and not the total ready of the screen

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;


const SignUpScreen = () => {
  // ...

  const handleDateChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || birthdate;
    setShowDatePicker(false);
    setBirthdate(currentDate);
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <InputField
          label="Geburtsdatum"
          value={birthdate}
          onDateChange={() => setShowDatePicker(true)}
          required
          error={errors.birthdate}
        />
        {showDatePicker && (
          <DateTimePicker
            style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH }} // Setze die Breite des DateTimePicker auf die Bildschirmbreite
            value={birthdate}
            mode="date"
            display="spinner"
            onChange={handleDateChange}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I37jd.jpg)

I want to display InputField of DateTimePicker on the total width, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

just find in those native code, you can see all the supported property:

```
RCT_EXPORT_SHADOW_PROPERTY(date, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_SHADOW_PROPERTY(mode, UIDatePickerMode)
RCT_EXPORT_SHADOW_PROPERTY(locale, NSLocale)
RCT_EXPORT_SHADOW_PROPERTY(displayIOS, RNCUIDatePickerStyle)


RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(date, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(locale, NSLocale)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(minimumDate, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(maximumDate, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(minuteInterval, NSInteger)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(enabled, BOOL)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onChange, RCTBubblingEventBlock)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onPickerDismiss, RCTBubblingEventBlock)


RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(mode, datePickerMode, UIDatePickerMode)
RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(timeZoneOffsetInMinutes, timeZone, NSTimeZone)
```

from [here](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/blob/0e1f0cb4e7fb089f7c4615dcc5e91333fe136dfe/ios/RNDateTimePickerManager.m#L103-L118)

The second: This lib using native DatePickerIOS, so you better lets it's choose the size automatically by system